# How to remove an element from list using the yaml-cpp 0.5.0 API

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

The following test code does not remove an element from the list as expected:

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::Load("[1,2,3]");
node.remove(1); // expect that this should remove the middle element from the list

ofstream ofs("test.yml");
ofs << node;
ofs.close();
```

The test output file contains:

```
-1
-2
-3
```

It appears that the file contains the value from the original list and the element was not removed. What is the correct way to remove an element from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this now (I didn't think of this!). I've filed a bug (http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=190), but I'm not sure what the syntax should be. Please comment on that issue if you have suggestions!

Comment: It has been fixed in version 0.6.3